# how do force enable button in menu items using handles value and make sure click even fires

Tags: vb6

how do i enable a menu item and make sure the click even fires? .

i have app1 and app2

**app2** has
3 menu items
gold
silver
bronze

i setted option  **enabled = false**
in all 3 item click events i have msgbox,  so when its clicked i know msgbox fired up and its working.

=======================================

**app1**
has the code below , i have an image which i drag to app1 to get the windows handle value and then get the menu handles value,  with each menu handle value i insert it to text2.text and enable the menu button.

```
Public Declare Function EnableWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long


Private Sub Command5_Click()
 EnableWindow Text2.Text, 1 ' Enable < This is the API call
        ControllEnabled = True ' Sets Swich
End Sub
```

when i enable the each menu item using the handle value the menu item then becomes clickable , when i click it, it dont fire the msgbox ? how come
**module**

```
'Public verables
Public ControllEnabled As Boolean
Public CursorPosition As POINT
Public Targeting As Boolean

'User defined type
Public Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Public Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
```

Comment: `EnableMenuItem`
The EnableMenuItem function enables, disables, or grays the specified menu item.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fire the MsgBox because you haven't written click event handlers for your menu item.  Also, you don't need to use the API to do what you need to do, and I don't recommend that you do so.  It's easier to use the built-in event handlers.

I'll refer you to Microsoft's [Using Menus in Your Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262292(v=vs.60).aspx) from the VB6 doc.  I suggest you scrap your existing code, read all of this, and start over. Menus aren't as difficult as you are making them and you will save a lot of time if you adopt the more usual method of menu creation.